# Storing student names and quiz scores in array

Tags: java, arrays

For an assignment, I am being asked to have

- A one-dimensional array to store five student names, and
- A two-dimensional array to store names and quiz scores.

I have the following code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    java.util.Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] n = {"Jessica", "Tom", "Sandy", "Jimmy", "Leah"};
    double [][] m = {
        {90,70,0},
        {70,80,0}, 
        {50,80,0}, 
        {90,10,0}, 
        {40,30,0}
    };
    // Remaining code
}
```

I have the student names in the one-dimensional array and quiz scores in the two-dimensional array, but when I try to put names into the two-dimensional array, I keep getting errors.

Do I have to change the data type for the 2D array? How would I fix this?

Comment: "I keep getting errors" What are the errors? The fact that you write `java.util.Scanner` suggests you're not importing `Scanner` - so you'd get an error when you then say `new Scanner`. Try adding `import java.util.Scanner;`.

Comment: how are you gonna save names in 2d array when you declared it as double?

Comment: I think you have misinterpreted the assignment.  The array of names is related to the array of scores by its index position, i.e. the first name in the name array (`n[0]`) corresponds to the first row in the array of scores (`m[0][]`).  While this is the assignment, you should be aware that this technique, called "parallel arrays" is a really bad way to represent information in modern Object-Oriented languages.  I hope your teacher tells you this and shows you better ways to do this.

Comment: You probably have misunderstood the task. Why sould you store the names twice?

Comment: i didnt misunderstood the task. this is what is he asking for.    1) inside the main method, define a 1-D array that can store 5 student names. Define a 2-D array inside the main method that stores students(rows) exam record that each student has 3 data fields (columns): 2 scores & average of the scores.    2) assign student names and quiz scores to the 2-D array

Comment: @JimGarrison: Yes, this is very bad style not only in OOP but also structured languages like C and even Pascal where you would use structs to represent the data.

Comment: @JimGarrison he did this part for us in class, i just copied what he wrote on the board

Comment: @Amanda the assignment doesn't look like correct English to me. It also says that the array should have 3 columns, but then asks to store the names in it. What you should simply do is go ask for clarifications to your teacher. There are many ways to model student names, scores and averages in Java, but the proper way would not use 2D arrays. So go see your teacher.

Comment: There is only one scenario in which this assignment makes sense: The teacher is showing the students how it used to be in the ancient days before data structures were available, for example Fortran or BASIC in the 1960s.  The "parallel array" technique is to modern data structures as a stone blade is to a scalpel -- i.e. extremely primitive.  I hope the teacher follows up by carefully explaining that this is NOT the way things are done today.  And even then I can't really see the point.  We don't ask medical students to perform surgery with stone tools before they're given a scalpel.

Answer (score 0):

Well a 2D array is either one type or another. You cannot have it be a double on the first array and a String in the other.

You cannot store names as doubles but you can store a double as a String.

Instead you can make the array a String and put the scores as Strings ("10") instead of 10, because you want a uniform data type. So for example

`String[][] scores = {{"Bob, "Tom", "Kim"}, {"100","50","95"}};`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object` instead.
All classes inherit from `Object`.

```
String[] n = {"Jessica", "Tom", "Sandy", "Jimmy", "Leah"};
Object [][] m = {
        {n[0], 90, 70, 0},
        {n[1], 70, 80, 0},
        {n[2], 50, 80, 0},
        {n[3], 90, 10, 0},
        {n[4], 40, 30, 0},
};
```

Normally an instance of `Map` would suffice and make it look and feel better ;)

Comment: While this is correct, it absolutely makes no sense, as @JimGarrison has explained in his comment.

Comment: Yep, just noticed.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a `Map` to put students names and them quiz scores like this :

```
Map<String, Integer[]> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Jessica", new Integer[]{70, 80, 0});
map.put("Tom", new Integer[]{70, 80, 0});
map.put("Sandy", new Integer[]{50, 80, 0});
map.put("Jimmy", new Integer[]{90, 10, 0});
map.put("Leah", new Integer[]{40, 30, 0});
```

So if you want to get the scores of a student you can make :

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(map.get("Jessica")));
```

Comment: That would be preferable but they say it is for an assignment, so there are guidelines to be followed (must be a 2D array)